# How to put swiper into bootstrap 4 modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I tried to insert swiper carousel into bootstrap modal 4 and it works only after resizing the screen.

I found the example where a guy had the same problem. He solved it using setTimeout (). The code looks:

```
setTimeout(function() {

var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: 10000,
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true
});
```

}, 0);

For my case it haven't worked.. [Here](https://mivimebel.ru/portfolio/) you see my problem. Just click on the button **Tap Here**.

Thanks!

Comment: Add some more info. The link what you gave is working properly. If you rephrase the problem, it'll be easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: Check it out please. On the video i showed what trouble is.
https://www.screencast.com/t/iq1eYFJGPVPl